# jQuery - ajax can't return varchar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax for search results from mysql database. After ajax onclick(selecting result) returns unknown number when type of field is varchar(50). At field integer(8) it works fine. What is the difference?
My code:

index.php

```
$('#konto').keyup(function() {
                    var konto = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'konto.php',
                        data: {
                            search: konto
                        },
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#konto').css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
                        },

                        success: function(data) {
                            if (!data.error) {
                                $('#selectKonto').show();
                                $('#selectKonto').html(data);
                                $("#konto").css("background", "#FFF");


                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                function selectKonto(val) {
            $("#konto").val(val);
            $("#selectKonto").hide();

        }
```

konto.php

```
if(!empty($konto)) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM konto WHERE kp_sif LIKE '$konto%' OR kp_ko LIKE '%$konto%' OR UPPER(kp_n1) LIKE '%$konto%' OR UPPER(kp_n2) LIKE '%$konto%' LIMIT 200";
    $result = $db->query($q);

    if(!$result){
        die('QUERY FAILED' . $db->error);
    }
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<font size="2em"><a href="#" class="list-group-item konto" style="width: 255px;border: 1px solid grey;"
            onClick="selectKonto('.$row['kp_sif'].')">
...
```

Comment: as an aside, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should research using parameterised queries to reduce the risk of this, otherwise someone could easily steal, corrupt or destroy your data by submitting a malicious piece of data. There are plenty of tutorials on this for PHP/MySQL (or whatever DB you're using) online.

Comment: @ADyson okay thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the argument to `selectKonto()` if the value is a string.

```
        echo '<font size="2em"><a href="#" class="list-group-item konto" style="width: 255px;border: 1px solid grey;"
        onClick="selectKonto(\''.$row['kp_sif'].'\')">
```

Comment: Hi sir. After putting quotes, clicking on results works fine but still kp_sif does not return data from mysql database. 
Onclick now don't work correctly, number which one I searched stays in input.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it doesn't work correctly. Can you see it if you do View Source?

Comment: No sir. I can see it only on row when it calling ajax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143952/discussion-between-barmar-and-proofzy).